# Extjs Grid - get exactly destination position after drag

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4

I have a 'gridpanel' example:

id

--

1

2

3

4
It can drop drag. When i drag 2 to after 3. It's say (drag 2 before 4).
i want get exactly destination position after drag that's not depending before or after.
(so above example, output's should 3) thanks

```
listeners: {
  drop: function(node, data, dropRec, dropPosition) {
     var dropOn = dropRec ? ' ' + dropPosition + ' ' + dropRec.get('id') : ' on empty view';
     Ext.example.msg("Drag from left to right", 'Dropped ' + data.records[0].get('id') + dropOn);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution from http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?237426-Getting-Row-Index-from-second-Grid-when-data-dropped-in-first-Grid.

Using

```
var record = data.records[0],
index = g1.getView().indexOf(record);     
alert(index);
```